# the import.org.opencv.R.id cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have a project using open c v . and I get a error with import .org . open c v .R.id cannot be resolved . can you help me ?

I already clean project but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have imported your own projects R class rather than android's default R class.
For example: **your.app.package.R**.
And then do a "clean project".

Comment: could you explain in more detail . because i am import project from github